# Programmatically redirect HTTP Request from GET to POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Below is the method signature of a `POST` controller action.

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Find(AgentViewModel agent)
```

The `POST` method accepts a view model object as an input parameter. The `GET` method, however, is naturally empty like so:

```
    public ActionResult Find()
```

We want to be able to access the `POST` action from two pages. From one page, we use a form. The form data is serialized into the view model object, and the action is called appropriately. The second page, however, contains a hyperlink with an `id` value appended as a query string (`id` is a property of the view model object).

So essentially we are trying to access the `Find` `POST` method two different ways: through a form which serializes the data into the view model object, and through a hyperlink containing a query string.

My question is twofold: I have an override on the controllers `Initialize` method that examines the `RequestContext` object for the presence of the the query string. Since an object has not been serialized I would like, if the parameter is found, to create the view model object and serialize it into the `HTTPRequest`. Since the request was originally being sent to the `GET` method, I would also like to redirect to the `POST` action.

There are easier hacks/workarounds for this problem (i.e. adding null paramters, using a redirect in the `GET`), however I'd like to find a solution that customizes the pipeline simply as a challenge. Any direction/ideas greatly appreciated.

```
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() == "Find" &&
            requestContext.RouteData.Values.Count > 2)
        {
            if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] != null)
            {
                string agentId = requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
                AgentViewModel model = new AgentViewModel();
                model.AgentId = agentId;

                //Need to find a way to redirect from the GET to the POST method
                //Need to find a way to add the AgentViewModel object to the request

                ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(this.ControllerContext, "Find");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn´t it be easier if in your html instead of a hyperlink, you had a form with a submit button? That would go directly to the post request and the id can still come in the query string.

Comment: There are a number of easier ways to handle this. Like I said in the post though, I want to find a solution that customizes something in the pipeline as  challenge/learning experience.